# How can I unwind to the MainView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I can't find a way to go to the ContentView from ViewB without showing a secound `NavigationView` on top of the other `NavigationView`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                Text("Go to ViewA")
                NavigationLink(destination: ViewA()) {Text("Go")}
            }.navigationBarTitle("ContentView")
        }
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
   @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Go to ViewB")
            NavigationLink(destination: ViewB()) {Text("Go to B")}
            Text("Go back")
            Button(action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {Text("Go to ContentView")}
        }.navigationBarTitle("ViewA")
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Go Home")
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {Text("Go")}
            Text("Go back")
            Button(action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {Text("Go to ViewB")}
        }.navigationBarTitle("ViewB")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

In the "old" Swift i could easily make an unwindSegue like

```
@IBAction func unwindToVCMain(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { }
}
```

and easily call it like

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToVcMain", sender: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: I am also looking for something similar.

Answer (score 4):

## in iOS16 and above

The new programmatic way to do navigation is extremely powerful! Much better than the old one.
The new way is using the `NavigationStack(path:root)`.
The path parameter is a Binding to a `NavigationPath`. ex.

```swift
@State private var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
           ...
    }
```

Lets create two structs to illustrate how this works.

```swift
struct Fruit: Hashable,Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var number: Int
    static var sample = [Fruit(name: "Apple", number: 2), Fruit(name: "Cherry", number: 3)]
}

struct Vegetable: Hashable,Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var number: Int
    static var sample = [Vegetable(name: "Carrot", number: 2), Vegetable(name: "Zucchini", number: 3)]
}
```

The new navigation style is data driven.
Here I create the label and link...
`NavigationLink(value:label:)`
But the destination will be different if I have a fruit or a veg.

```swift
 .navigationDestination(for: Fruit.self) { fruit in
     VStack {
     ...
     }
```

So if I have a Vegetable or a Fruit model, depending of the data type selected in the link, the navigation destination will be different and it will present different views.

So let's put this in the NavigationStack. Lets start with the NavigationLink:

```swift
Form {
    Section("Fruits") {
       ForEach(Fruit.sample) { fruit in
          NavigationLink(value: fruit) {
               HStack {
                 Text("\(fruit.number)")
                 Text(fruit.name)
               }
           }
       }
    }
    Section("Veggies") {
        ForEach(Vegetable.sample) { fruit in
           NavigationLink(value: fruit) {
                 HStack {
                   Text("\(fruit.number)")
                   Text(fruit.name)
                 }
             }
           }
         }
     }
```

Now the `NavigationDestination` gonna look like this:

```swift
 .navigationDestination(for: Fruit.self) { fruit in
     VStack {
         Text(fruit.name)
         HStack{
             let count = path.count
             Text("level: \(count)")
         }
         Form {
             Section("Veggies") {
                 ForEach(Vegetable.sample) { veg in
                     NavigationLink(value: veg) {
                         HStack {
                             Text("\(veg.number)")
                             Text(veg.name)
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         Button("Unwind") {
             path.removeLast(path.count)
         }
     }
```

and below add again the same but for veggies like:

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: Vegetable.self) { veg in
         VStack {
                   ...
}
```

Now you can navigate from list to list and the app will show you how many level deep you are depending of how many items are collected in the path. Then you can unwind. This will reset the path property to empty and the start page will be shown again!

The screen will look like this... and the unwind button

[image: fridge]

and navigating...

[image: navigation]

I hope this helps!

## For iOS 15 and below

### Using the old `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink(destination:isactive:label)`

First, embed your first view in a navigation controller.

Then you insert a navigation link to the next view. The NavigationLink has different initialisers.
Choose this one with the `isActive` parameter:

[image: ScreenshotNavLink]

It is a bit mind-bending at first, but the `isActive` parameter in the `NavigationLink` becomes `true` when the link is clicked and the navigation moves to the next screen.

> It creates an instance that presents a destination when active

If I pass a binding keeping track of the state of this property, if at any time in my subsequent chain of views I set it to false again, it will reset and return to the original screen! It is quite neat!!

See this short example in code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isActive: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SecondView(isActive: $isActive),
                isActive: $isActive,
                label: {
                    Text("Go to second View")
                })
                .navigationTitle("MainView")
        }
    }
}
```

My second View:

```swift
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var isActive: Bool

    var body: some View {
            NavigationLink("Go to Third View",destination:  ThirdView(isActive: $isActive))
                .navigationTitle("Second View")
    }
}
```

And here the button to unwind, but it could be in any view.
Setting `isActive = false` does some magic here!

```swift
struct ThirdView: View {
    @Binding var isActive: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("Unwind!"){
            isActive = false
        }
        .navigationTitle("Last View!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for that method.
I adopted calling `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` twice, but it is not exactly same behave as unwind transaction.