# SwiftUI programmatic navigation issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm following Paul Hudson's article on [programmatic navigation](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui) although I'm getting errors.

I've recreated the error using three simple views. What I'm trying to do is move from ContentView -> ChildViewOne -> ChildViewTwo -> ContentView.

I get the following error going from ChildViewTwo -> ContentView:

2021-05-20 15:06:44.346713+1200 Test[7756:137785] [Assert] UIScrollView does not support multiple observers implementing *observeScrollView:willEndDraggingWithVelocity:targetContentOffset:unclampedOriginalTarget:. Scroll view <*TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView: 0x7fb75a8df000; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 390 844); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000016fe730>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000181a960>; contentOffset: {0, -239}; contentSize: {390, 169.33333333333334}; adjustedContentInset: {239, 0, 34, 0}; dataSource: <*TtGC7SwiftUIP13$7fff56921d2819ListCoreCoordinatorGVS_20SystemListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxS2***: 0x7fb75980e410>>, new observer <*TtGC7SwiftUI41StyleContextSplitViewNavigationControllerVS_19SidebarStyleContext*: 0x7fb758855000>, removing old observer <*TtGC7SwiftUI41StyleContextSplitViewNavigationControllerVS_19SidebarStyleContext*: 0x7fb75902ca00>

I also get double navigation when going back to ContentView.

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isShowingChildOne = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    VStack {
                        
                        // Programmatic navigation here
                        NavigationLink(destination: ChildViewOne(), isActive: $isShowingChildOne) { EmptyView() }
                        Button("Next") {
                            self.isShowingChildOne = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle("ContentView")
        }
    }
}
```

ChildViewOne

```
struct ChildViewOne: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(0..<5) { item in
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildViewTwo()) {
                Text("Hello")
            }.navigationTitle("Child One")
        }
    }
}
```

ChildViewTwo

```
struct ChildViewTwo: View {
    
    @State private var isShowingContentView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello")
            
            .navigationTitle("Child Two")
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    VStack {
                        
                        // Programmatic navigation here
                        NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), isActive: $isShowingContentView) { EmptyView() }
                        Button("Add") {
                            self.isShowingContentView = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59479536/how-can-i-unwind-to-the-mainview-in-swiftui